# Python package not being found after install

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I have a project directory structure like this:

```
   root\
      .git\
      server\
         setup.py
         company\
            __init__.py
            zed\
                __init__.py
                server\
                    __init__.py
                    server.py
                    util.py
```

My *__init__.py* files are all empty. My *root\server\setup.py* looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="zed-server",
    version="1.0.0",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        # ...
    ]
)
```

I confirmed that `find_packages()` is returning:

```
['company', 'company.zed', 'company.zed.server']
```

I install the package (successfully) by doing:

```
cd root\server
pip install -e .
```

I confirm the package is installed as editable:

```
$ pip list
...
zed-server          1.0.0     C:\path\to\root\server
...
```

---

The problem:

In *server.py* I have an import statement like this:

```
import company.zed.server.util
```

I run that file like:

```
cd root\server\company\zed\server
python server.py
```

But it fails with:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'company.zed.server'
```

And I have no idea what's going on. Why can't it find the package and how do I resolve this?

System:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.11.1
- Pip 23.3.1
- Setuptools 68.2.2

Comment: You should always run like this: `python -m company.zed.server.server`. No need to change into the lower directory. -- https://sinoroc.github.io/kb/python/python_imports.html

Comment: @sinoroc Huh, that solves *this* problem (I don't know why), but it introduces a new one. I simplified my question a little; there is a second directory under *root* that also has its own *setup.py* and provides modules like *company.zed.common.xyz*. Running with `python -m` lets it find *company.zed.server* but it is still complaining about *company.zed.common* from the other package. --- Is it possible this is an XY problem and my real issue is multiple packages providing *company.zed...*?

Comment: Probably. Look up "namespace packages", and only pay attention to "native namespace packages", ignore the rest (outdated). https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/ -- Basically you should remove `company/__init__.py` and `company/zed/__init__.py` in both projects. -- If there is no `__init__.py` in directory `X` but there is one a sub-diretory of `X`, then `X` is a "namespace package". A namespace package can be shared by multiple separately installable projects.

Comment: @sinoroc That's 100% what it was!! I removed the `__init__.py` files from the intermediate directories and everything started working. I lost about a half a day to this today, thank you so much!!

Comment: Except on MacOS (Python 3.9, 3.10, and 3.11) it says `No module named 'company'`... argh...

Comment: Hard to tell what is happening on your computer. Maybe double check that you are using the same Python interpreter to install and to run, in other words use `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install ...` and then `path/to/pythonX.Y -m company.zed.server.server`: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @sinoroc For some reason the behavior is different on macOS. I had to change the `setup` call to do `packages=['company.zed.server']` (instead of `find_packages()`) and then set `namespace_packages=['company', 'company.zed']` and it seemed to work on macOS. I still haven't had a chance to see if that still works on Windows.

Comment: ^^^ Yes, this works on Windows and Linux as well.

Answer (score 0):

As your driver file is server.py and util.py is in same directory as server.py
Try the following...

```
import util
```

Util.py has only one line in my case that is printing hello.

```
print("Hello")
```

**Output: **

[image]

Comment: I tried running `python` from *root* and doing this, and it says `No module named 'root'`.

Comment: What's your driver file that running on startup?

Comment: *root/server/company/zed/server/server.py*, which I run as `python server.py` from *root/server/company/zed/server*.

Comment: If your start file is server.py, then just by "import util" will work fine

Comment: Well, I simplified my question a little and there's still problems with other `company.zed.*` packages (some in other repos). So that would solve it for this file but I still need the absolute imports to work.

Comment: Wait a minute... if one project creates a package named *a.b.c* and a totally separate project creates a package named *a.b.d*, will that cause problems (because two projects are providing *a.b*?)

Comment: No, it will not cause any problem because abspath of every project will be diffierent. So it doesn't matter